# Doubling the cube with rational Meccano strips

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization, mechanical-puzzles, construction

In three monographs published in [2006](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ehooft101/lectures/meccano.pdf), [2008](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ehooft101/lectures/meccano2.pdf) and [2014](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ehooft101/lectures/meccano3.pdf) Gerard 't Hooft considered "Meccano mathematics": how to construct specified distances and regular polygons by a rigid system of ideal Meccano strips, where the distance between adjacent holes on a strip is 1. He showed in the first monograph that all regular polygons can be constructed this way, but there is a stronger result:

> **Theorem** ([Maehara 1991](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X9190070D)). A positive real number can be constructed (*braced*) as the distance between two holes in a rigid Meccano linkage iff it is algebraic, even if all the strips are of length 1.

Based on this, here is a generalisation I have thought of:

1. The strips have no discrete holes on them and may be arbitrarily long
2. On the same strip all distances between hinges and measurement points (for the specified distance) must be **rational numbers** (but these numbers can be arbitrarily large, numerator or denominator alike)
3. The objective is to use as few strips as possible while keeping rigidity
4. Everything is in the Euclidean plane
5. No other tools (pencil, paper, compasses, sliders, etc.) are allowed; the strips may only be connected to each other through hinges

Here is an example valid construction for the golden ratio $\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$:

[image]

The puzzle here is to **brace $\sqrt[3]2$ following the rules above**, hence doubling the cube. Since the number is a root of $x^3-2$, it is algebraic and the theorem implies that a solution to the puzzle exists; answers should explain why $\sqrt[3]2$ is exactly attained and why their system is rigid.

---

<sub>This puzzle is an offspring of some questions I've asked on the Maths Stack; cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2675079/357390), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3609754/357390), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3604438/357390) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3606490/357390).</sub>

> There is a solution with 13 strips obtainable from 't Hooft's monographs, but I strongly suspect it can be done in fewer, perhaps as little as 5.

Comment: Something like [spoiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube#Using_a_marked_ruler)?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. Aren't the strips just like marked rulers? What specifically is not allowed in the linked construction? I don't see where a compass is required. This seems to be quite a specialist topic, so it would do no harm to explain for dummies.

Comment: Sorry, you completely lost me.What's the difference between drawing a triange and joining three strips of suitable lengths at their ends?

Comment: @loopywalt In the first case, you have implicitly used a piece of paper, which is not allowed.

Comment: @loopywalt Segments CD CG and CH probably have irrational lengths, which I guess isn't allowed by rule 2.

Comment: Is there a way to apply the function $f(1) = 1+1/(x^2+x+1)$ infinite times without violating the rules?

Comment: @Nautilus How would that work? All constructions must use a finite number of strips .

Comment: If "_The strips have no discrete holes on them and may be arbitrarily long_" what has this to do with Meccano? The original monographs quoted all deal with the regular spaced holes in Meccano strips of (an assortment of) predefined lengths.

Comment: @quiklin Any rational bracing as I've defined it can be turned into a Meccano bracing by clearing denominators. Since it is possible to get all rational lengths through only Meccano strips with hole spacing 1, this does not increase nor decrease the expressive power; my formalisation is just a convenience.

Comment: So you are asking for $\sqrt[3]2$ as a ratio between two lengths.  In the example, the bar marked phi would be of length 88*phi when using unit mecanos.

Comment: "Aren't the strips just like marked rulers? What specifically is not allowed in the linked construction?" Meccano strips can only measure rational distances, so the rays CF and CE don't exist.